# parallelize zonal computation on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I try to compute mode on all cells of the same zone (same value) on a numpy array. I give you an example of code below. In this example sequential approach works fine but multiprocessed approach does nothing. I do not find my mistake.

Does someone see my error ?

I would like to parallelize the computation because my real array is a 10k * 10k array with 1M zones.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import multiprocessing as mp

def zone_mode(i, a, b, output):
    to_extract = np.where(a == i)
    val = b[to_extract]
    output[to_extract] = ss.mode(val)[0][0]
    return output

def zone_mode0(i, a, b):
    to_extract = np.where(a == i)
    val = b[to_extract]
    output = ss.mode(val)[0][0]
    return output

np.random.seed(1)

zone = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
                 [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                 [4, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                 [4, 4, 5, 5, 3],
                 [4, 6, 6, 5, 5],
                 [6, 6, 6, 5, 5]])
values = np.random.randint(8, size=zone.shape)

output = np.zeros_like(zone).astype(np.float)

for i in np.unique(zone):
    output = zone_mode(i, zone, values, output)

# for multiprocessing    
zone0 = zone - 1

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1)
results = [pool.apply(zone_mode0, args=(u, zone0, values)) for u in np.unique(zone0)]
pool.close()
output = results[zone0]
```

Comment: what is the range for your `values`?

Comment: the range for zone is 1 to 1 460 548 with missing values in. But I can update the range from 0 to 1 020 089. The range for values can varry accordig to my case study : [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 61] or [111, 112, 212, 213, 411, 311, 312, 313, ...]

Comment: @user7017404 Any feedback on the posted solution?

Comment: I am preparing my data to test it. I come back for the feedback asap. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positve integers in the arrays - `zone` and `values`, we can use `np.bincount`. The basic idea is that we will consider `zone` and `values` as row and cols on a 2D grid. So, can map those to their linear index equivalent numbers. Those would be used as bins for binned summation with `np.bincount`. Their `argmax` IDs would be the mode numbers. They are mapped back to *zone-grid* with indexing into `zone`.

Hence, the solution would be -

```
m = zone.max()+1
n = values.max()+1
ids = zone*n + values
c = np.bincount(ids.ravel(),minlength=m*n).reshape(-1,n).argmax(1)
out = c[zone]
```

---

For sparsey data (well spread integers in the input arrays), we can look into sparse-matrix to get the argmax IDs `c`. Hence, with SciPy's sparse-matrix -

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

data = np.ones(zone.size,dtype=int)
r,c = zone.ravel(),values.ravel()
c = coo_matrix((data,(r,c))).argmax(1).A1
```

For slight perf. boost, specify the shape -

```
c = coo_matrix((data,(r,c)),shape=(m,n)).argmax(1).A1
```

---

**Solving for generic `values`**

We will make use of `pandas.factorize`, like so -

```
import pandas as pd

ids,unq = pd.factorize(values.flat)
v = ids.reshape(values.shape)
# .. same steps as earlier with bincount, using v in place of values
out = unq[c[zone]]
```

Note that for tie-cases, it would pick random element off `values`. If you want to pick the first one, use `pd.factorize(values.flat, sort=True)`.

Comment: Your solution (with bincount) is beyond my expectation. Less than 10s on my data. Thank you so much.